# How do I add text on the 2nd line of a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Suppose my string is:

```
 var string ="abcd                  
 acdcd  
 ejhwejeh  
 kjkjewkjkejw";
```

and I want to add a text in front of the 2nd line called "hello " so it becomes.

```
string ="abcd                  
 hello acdcd  
 ejhwejeh  
 kjkjewkjkejw";
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Neither of these two are actually valid JavaScript strings

Answer (score 1):

Split the string at the newlines with

```
var arr = string.split(/\r?\n/);
```

That gives you an array with the single words, which you can put together again with the new word.

```
var string2  = '';  

    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
      string2 = string2 + arr[i]
}

string2 = arr[0] + 'hello' + string2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string with linefeed and change the array with the wanted part and joinf the array to a new string.

```js
var string ="abcd\nacdcd\nejhwejeh\nkjkjewkjkejw",
    temp = string.split(/\n/);

temp[1] = 'hello ' + temp[1];

console.log(temp.join('\n'));
```